# How can I derive a second order implicit method for this coupled ODE update?

Tags: implicit-methods

I appreciate this might be an easy question, but I've managed to get myself quite thoroughly confused
I'm trying to solve a system of physics equations that look as follows
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}=-\alpha \mathbf{j} \\
 \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}}{\partial t}=\beta\mathbf{E}+\gamma\mathbf{j}\times\mathbf{B}
$$
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are scalar constants and $\mathbf{B}$ is a constant vector with 3 components. $\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{j}$ also both have 3 components.
I would like to solve these equations implicitly. I can easily work out the 1st order implicit Euler method, it ends up with something like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{E} \\
\mathbf{j}
\end{pmatrix}^{n}=\underline{\mathbf{M}}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{E} \\
\mathbf{j}
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}
$$
where $\mathbf{M}$ is just some 6x6 matrix I can invert through some linear algebra routine. However, I am finding that this implicit Euler method for solving this problem isn't sufficiently accurate and I would like a second order method. I just can't work out how to apply a second order method to this problem.
I've been thinking about using Crank-Nicholson, which for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = f(t, y)$ can be written like
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n + \frac{h}{2}(k_1 + k_2) \\
k_1 = f(t_n, y_n) \\
k_2 = f(t_n + h, y_n + \frac{h}{2}(k_1 + k_2))
$$
But I can't get my head around how you solve the last step for $k_2$ for my problem when it isn't so much a function of $f(t, y)$ as much as a sort of matrix product like
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{E} \\
\mathbf{j} \\ 
\end{pmatrix} = \underline{\mathbf{M}}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{E} \\ \mathbf{j} \end{pmatrix}
$$ I don't have a good conception of what $k_1$ or $k_2$ actually look like for my problem.

I think they should look something like
$$
\mathbf{k_1} = \underline{\mathbf{M}}\cdot\mathbf{y}^n \\
\mathbf{k_2} = \underline{\mathbf{M}}\cdot(\mathbf{y}^n + \frac{h}{2}\underline{\mathbf{M}}\cdot\mathbf{y}^n + \frac{h}{2}\mathbf{k_2})
$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ is the vector of $\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{j}$. But is this remotely correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the linear case you get
$$k_1+k_2=2My+\frac h2 M(k_1+k_2),$$
so that isolating the sum you get
$$k_1+k_2=2(I-hM/2)^{-1}My.$$
For the step this gives
$$
y^{n+1}=y^n+\frac h2(k_1+k_2)=y^n+(I-hM/2)^{-1}hMy^n
\\
=(I-hM/2)^{-1}[(I-hM/2)+hM]y^n=(I-hM/2)^{-1}(I+hM/2)y^n
$$
as one also gets directly from the trapezoidal formula
$$
\frac{y^{n+1}-y^n}h=\frac{My^n+My^{n+1}}2
$$

---

Practically one could most easily solve for the mean slope $k_m=\frac{k_1+k_2}2$, as then
$$
k_m=\frac{f(t^n,y^n)+f(t^{n+1},y^n+hk_m)}2.
$$
If $J$ is a sufficiently accurate approximation of the Jacobian around $(t^n,y^n)$, then $f(t^{n+1},y^n+hk_m)-hJk_m$ will be nearly flat as function of $k_m$ and small $h$, so that the fixed-point iteration
$$
k_m^{new}=(I-hJ/2)^{-1}\frac{f(t^n,y^n)+f(t^{n+1},y^n+hk_m^{old})-hJk_m^{old}}2
$$
Here "flat" implies a small Lipschitz constant of $O(h^2)$ for this iteration. This is usually sufficient to get good enough approximation in 1-3 iterations, as the error in the fixed-point equation decreases by a factor $O(h^2)$ in each step. So starting with $k_m=k_1$, after one step the error is $O(h^4)$ and thus smaller than the $O(h^3)$ error for the method step.